# split string into array with multiple delimiters shell

Tags: arrays, bash, delimiter, split

I have a text file having contents in format...

```
File=/opt/mgtservices/probes/logs is_SS_File=no is_Log=yes Output_File=probes_logs
```

This can have around 1k records. I am reading line by line from a file.

```
while read -r line
do
  if [ $SS_SERVER -eq 0 ]
  then
    arr=$(echo "$line" | tr ' =' "\n")
    echo $arr[1]
    #do something
  elif [[ $SS_SERVER -eq 1 && "$line" =~ "is_SS_File=\"no\"" ]]
  then
    #do something else
  fi
done < "$filename"
```

I am expecting that arr should be an array, so that I can get output as:

```
arr[1]=File
arr[2]=/opt/mgtservices/probes/logs
arr[3]=is_SS_File
and so on...
```

Which I am not getting here. arr[1] is giving me complete line without "="
I want to use 2 delimiters "space" and "=".

Comment: What is the meaning and significance of `SS_SERVER` and where is it being set?

Comment: @tripleee...SS_SERVER is a flag which I can get from calling function. It can be 0 or 1.

Comment: Then it's not really relevant to your question, is it?

Comment: @triplee yes, you can say like that, basically my intention is to split string with multiple delimiters into array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish try this:

```
tr ' =' '\n ' <"$file" |
while read keyword value; do
    : you get one keyword and its value at a time now
done
```

or maybe

```
while IFS=' =' read -a arr; do
    : arr[0] is first keyword
    : arr[1] is its value
    : arr[2] is second keyword
    : etc
done <"$file"
```